# Icon text for PhoneJS app in PhoneGap not showing up in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build, phonejs

I have a relatively simple PhoneJS app wrapped in PhoneGap 2.9, being built using PhoneGap Build.  The app is using the NavBar layout.  When I load the app in Safari on an iPhone 5, the nav bar looks perfect, icons above text.  However, in PhoneGap, only the icons show up, no text.  I can't tell if the text is not rendering at all or if the entire app (or just nav bar) is pushed down below the screen, to the point where the text isn't showing.  I doubt it is the latter, because it would have to be pushed down just the perfect amount so that the icons render neatly, but the text is hidden.  Bottom line, why is the text not showing up in PhoneGap on iOS?  On Android, it works fine in PhoneGap (nav bar is at top of screen, with icons and text).

Here's the app init for the navigation:

```
MyApp.app = new DevExpress.framework.html.HtmlApplication({
    namespace: MyApp,
    navigationType: MyApp.config.navigationType,
    navigation: [
        {
            title: "Home",
            action: "#home",
            icon: "home"
        },
        {
            title: "My Library",
            action: "#library",
            icon: "favorites"
        },
        {
            title: "Settings",
            action: "#settings",
            icon: "info"
        }
    ]
});
```

Here's the meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

Don't know if anything in the config.xml is relevant, but I'd be happy to share that if need be.